# JS перенос строки в prompt

Tags: javascript, prompt, перенос-слов

возможно ли как-то сделать перенос строки в тексте **prompt**?

теги `<br>` и прочий html не работает.

`\n`
по аналогии с **alert** не работает -

`a = prompt('b\nc');`
выдает ошибку
***Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token***

Comment: Проблема не воспроизводится, перевод строки работает.  Скорее всего ошибка в другом месте.

Answer (score 1):

Вроде все работает

```js
prompt(`Как\nваши\nдела?`);
```

Answer (score 0):

спасибо
через обратные кавычки заработало

`` a = prompt(`b\nc`); ``